# Why is a default constructor created even though my abstract class has a protected constructor?

Tags: java, constructor, default-constructor

I have an abstract class `MousableActor` that extends a concrete class `Actor`:

```
public abstract class MousableActor extends Actor
{   
    /**
     * Constructs a MousableActor.
     */
    protected void MousableActor()
    {
    }
}
```

When I look at the javadoc generated for the class, I see a public no-args constructor:
[image: described in text]

According to [Section 8.8.9 of the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.9):

> If a class contains no constructor declarations, then a default constructor with no formal parameters and no throws clause is implicitly declared.

I always considered that an if-and-only-if. Why is a public default constructor being created even though I explicitly declared a protected constructor? Does it have something to do with [the superclass](http://www.greenfoot.org/files/javadoc/greenfoot/Actor.html) having a public no-args constructor?

I am using Greenfoot version 2.4.2 (which shouldn't matter) on top of Java 1.8.0.

Comment: If you had used a good IDE, it would have told you there was a problem, e.g. Eclipse shows the warning "This method has a constructor name".

Comment: Nice & clear question, lots of effort, though the solution is a little embarrassing :)

Comment: @zapl Lessons in humility are always good for a CS professor like me. My students love to hear about my mistakes, which make them feel better about theirs.

Comment: Should we add a tag pebcak?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A constructor is not a `void` method.

```
protected void MousableActor()
```

should be

```
protected MousableActor()
```

Comment: D'oh!  I hadn't realized that a method could have the same name as a constructor, not that I was conscious of having typed "void".

Answer (score 2):

Because it's returning `void`, it's not a constructor; it's a method, so there are no constructors, and the default constructor is created.

If you intend for that to be a constructor, then remove `void`.